# Metaphor and metaphors

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I see that the site has both "metaphor" as well as "metaphors" as tags. Granted, "metaphors" was only used once, but shouldn't is be eliminated or classified as a synonym tag to "metaphor?"

Answer (score 3):

Done, though the other way round, since we generally prefer plurals in tags.